# How do I call a another class from a class in java

Tags: java, class

I am trying to call another class that is in the same directory and is compiled. I keep getting the error symbol not found when I call the other class. Can anyone look at my code and see what I am doing incorrectly please.

This is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NameGameFrame extends JFrame
{
    public static String name;
    static JTextField textfield = new JTextField(20);
    static JTextArea  textarea = new JTextArea(30,30);

    public static void main( String[] args)
    {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Name Game");
        frame.setLocation(500,400);
        frame.setSize(800,800);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter the Name or Partial Name to search:");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(2,2,2,2);

        panel.add(label,c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(textarea,c);

        JButton button = new JButton("Search");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(button,c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(textfield,c);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                name = textfield.getText();
                java.io.File file = new java.io.File("namesdata.txt");
                try
                {
                    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
                    num = input.nextLine();
                    while (input.hasNext())
                    {
                        NameRecord(name); 
                    }
                }
                catch(FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    System.err.format("File does not exist\n");
                }
                textarea.setText(fields[0]);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

NameRecord is the name of the other class that I am calling. Also do I need to put something in the header of the second file class that I am calling?

Comment: Hi! Could you please next time simplify your application before you post it? I guess you can show the very save problem on application having 15 lines, so other programmers dont have to search where is the problematic line is. Thanks

Comment: Now that you've deleted your source code this is 'not a real question'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to an instance of `NameRecord` in the class that wants to call its methods.  I don't see one.  Did I miss it?  If not, add one.

I don't believe this is legal Java:

```
while (input.hasNext())
{
    NameRecord(name); 
}
```

You need to call `new` to invoke a constructor, as I see Martijn has pointed out.

Comment: What is the required syntax to reference an instance of NameRecord?

Comment: Martijn gave it to you: NameRecord nr = new NameRecord(name); This is Java 101.

Comment: Technically, the quoted code could be legal if it was contained in a class which declared a `NameRecord(String s)` method, or if such a static method was declared in another class, and imported using static import. While it would be possible, it would not be nice, as it would violate the java naming conventions.

Answer (score 3):

You can't call a class. You can call methods and constructors.

Your statement `NameRecord(name);` is nonsense. I think you want to call the constructor:

```
NameRecord record = new NameRecord(name);
```

Comment: That is what I want to do. But I'm not sure how to do it while passing name to the constructor of the other class file

Comment: Exactly as I wrote. You need a constructor `NameRecord(String name)`.

Answer (score 0):

In Place of this

```
  while (input.hasNext())
                {
                    NameRecord(name); 
                }
```

you have to make a object of that class

```
     while (input.hasNext())
                {
                    NameRecord record = new NameRecord(name); 
                }
```